# How to delete a NULL file from Solaris Unix?

Tags: solaris

I have a NULL file in a directory:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 blah1   blah2    83532 Nov  5 09:34   <can't see, but null here>
```

How do I remove this? This is very annoying as it interferes with `svn status`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete interactively, saying no to all of the non-null files.

> /bin/rm -i *

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using the iNode value (using the -i option on ls command)

```
# ls -li
total 16
  30475938 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           7 mar 19 10:29 -h
# find . -inum 30475938 -print
./-h
# find . -inum 30475938 -exec rm {} \;
# ls -li
total 0
```

In my blog, you have some examples -in Spanish- how to remove files with reserved characters.
http://sparcki.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/como-eliminar-archivos-utilizando-su.html

Urko,